# How to pass String value (filepath) dynamically in file class?

Tags: java, dynamic-arrays

```
String filepath=null;
public void dirScan()
    {
        File root = new File("/tmp/");
        FilenameFilter beginswithm = new FilenameFilter()
        {
         public boolean accept(File directory, String filename) {
              return filename.startsWith("201");
          }
        };

        File[] files = root.listFiles(beginswithm);
        for (File f: files)
        {
            filepath=f.toString();
            System.out.println(filepath);
        }
    }

public void prepDownload() throws Exception {

        File file = new File(filepath);
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        setDownload(new DefaultStreamedContent(input, externalContext.getMimeType(file.getName()), file.getName()));
        System.out.println("PREP = " + download.getName());

    }
public DefaultStreamedContent getDownload() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("GET = " + download.getName());

        return download;
    }
```

> I have a `tmp` folder in my system. This folder having some dynamic generated files. I want to pass filepath as dynamically `preDownload()` method. But in my method only last value of filepath is passed to `preDownlaod` method. while accessing `getDownload` method it fetches last filepath value. I want to download file from generated rows.Each row having unique file but in my case all rows having same file .

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that for each file found that matches your filter you want to pass to `prepDownload()` ? If so then you can try making the following changes:

```
...
for (File f: files){
    filepath=f.toString();
    prepDownload(filepath);
}
...
public void prepDownload(String filePath) throws Exception {
...
}
```

This will guarantee that as each file is found you will call prepDownload.

**Alternative Approach:**

Use a set to keep track of things instead. I.e.:

```
Set<String> filepaths = new HashSet<String>();
public void dirScan(){
    ...
    File[] files = root.listFiles(beginswithm);
    for (File f: files)
    {
        filepath=f.toString();
        filepaths.add(filepath);
    }
}
public void prepDownload() throws Exception {
    for(String filepath: filepaths){
        File file = new File(filepath);
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this one but again it is taking last value of the file path